# gtkmm: Simple example fails to compile: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, compilation, gtkmm, pkg-config, gtkmm3

I am working through the gtkmm documentation. I have started by trying to compile the "Simple Example". Here is the code. It can also be found [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en).

```
/// SimpleExample.cpp

#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto app =
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
      "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

  Gtk::Window window;
  window.set_default_size(200, 200);

  return app->run(window);
}
```

I have tried to compile this using

```
g++ SimpleExample.cpp -o SimpleExample `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

which should work according to the documentation. (See end of linked page.)

Running `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` produces

```
Package gtkmm-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtkmm-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtkmm-3.0' found
```

I am running Debian 9 Stretch. I installed `gtkmm` with

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install libgtkmm-3.0-dev
```

Running `find /usr -name "gtkmm"` produces

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gtkmm-3.0.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include/gtkmmconfig.h
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h
```

So why does the example not compile?

## Updates:

New terminal

```
pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs
Package gtkmm-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtkmm-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtkmm-3.0' found
```

Try

```
find /usr -name "*gtkmm-3.0*"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gtkmm-3.0.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1.1.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-3.0.so
/usr/share/doc/libgtkmm-3.0-1v5
/usr/share/doc/libgtkmm-3.0-dev
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0
```

Export location

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig"
```

Re-run

```
pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs
Package xproto was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xproto.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'xproto', required by 'xau', not found
```

(That's a different error this time.)

Try to find again

```
find /usr -name "*xproto*"
/usr/share/pkgconfig/xproto.pc
/usr/include/xcb/xproto.h
/usr/include/GL/glxproto.h
/usr/include/X11/extensions/lbxproto.h
```

Change export command

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig;/usr/share/pkgconfig"
```

Re-run, back to square 1

```
pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs
Package gtkmm-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtkmm-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtkmm-3.0' found
```

## Problem resolved (sort ot)

I have discovered from reading this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable) that the path should be colon seperated.

```
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig"
```

However this does not solve the problem of why this variable needs to be set at all. `pkg-config` is used because it is supposed to make compilation simpler, however this isn't any more simple than specifying the include paths manually, as multiple environment variables need to be set.

In addition, the lack of information about this issue online makes me suspect that this is an issue which most users do not encounter, and therefore is probably specific to Debian 9. (I would like to know if anyone else has encounted this problem, and on what OS.)

Comment: Try `find /usr -name "*gtkmm*"`

Comment: @n.m. Why? I can already see the header file. It is the final line of the output I posted above. `/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h` My question is why doesn't this compile considering that I can see where the header is.

Comment: Becaause you want to find your gtkmm.pc file. Read the message: `Perhaps you should add the directory containing \`gtkmm-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable`.

Comment: @n.m. You mean the first line in that block of code? The one that says `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gtkmm-3.0.pc` ?

Comment: Sorry missed it somehow. So `Perhaps you should add the directory containing \`gtkmm-3.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable` just as the message suggests.

Comment: @n.m. No problem but how? Surely this is the default directory where `pkg-config` looks?

Comment: @n.m. If I simply set it using `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/` then the same result occurs, presumably because this is the default location.

Comment: Perhaps it is not. Typically the default is /usr/lib/pkgconfig or somerhing like that.

Comment: @n.m. So, having set it, and found that it still doesn't work. What should I do next? I assume that the line of code above is the correct way to set this variable before running `g++`? If you don't actually know what you're doing then I would rather you just say so rather than us continuing to have a back and forth conversation which is isn't useful for anyone.

Comment: Say `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig` then run `strace -e open pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs |& fgrep gtkmm`. Do you see the gtkmm-3.0.pc file being opened? What is the return code?

Comment: Return code is `1`, the `trace` command does not print any output

Comment: I assume you mean `trace` not `strace`?

Comment: `strace command not found`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164560/discussion-between-n-m-and-user3728501).

Answer (score 0):

At first, it is normal that installing gtkmm is a bit complicated. As far as i can see, here in the Stackoverflow forum many users have problem with doing so. Even users in the Windows operating system are confronted with error messages, if they are trying to use gtkmm together with Visual Studio for developing a platform independent app ... But to your question. There are many options what can go wrong. A simple explanation would be, that the debian package “libgtk-3-dev” has to be installed, which is used for creating GTK+ apps in C, because gtkmm uses this package. So the first step is to try out, it the compilation of a C sourcecode for GTK+ works. A second explanation is, that the debian “package manager” is in general broken so switching the Linux distribution would be a good advice. For example, in Fedora a simple `dnf install gtk3 gtk3-devel gtkmm30 gtkmm30-devel` is enough for starting programming.