# CMake error with GTKmm - No package 'gtkmm-3.0' found

Tags: cmake, gtkmm, pkg-config, gtkmm3

This ***may*** be related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620635/gtkmm-simple-example-fails-to-compile-gtkmm-h-no-such-file-or-directory?noredirect=1#comment84242617_48620635).

I copied the code from the "Simple Example" [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en).

I copied the cmake instructions from [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/UsingCMake).

The error I am getting is:

```
-- Checking for module 'gtkmm-3.0'
--   No package 'gtkmm-3.0' found
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path-to-files/
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
project(SimpleExample)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig;/usr/share/pkgconfig")

pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-3.0)

link_directories(${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(SimpleExample SimpleExample.cpp)

target_link_libraries(SimpleExample ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})
```

There's a really dumb line in here `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig;/usr/share/pkgconfig")` which I'm fairly sure isn't supposed to be there, however in my previous question I was struggeling to figure out why `pkg-config` wasn't finding the correct locations for the `gtkmm-3.0.pc` file.

So I did a search to try and figure out how to set the paths for `pkg-config` manually in a CMake file. That is what I came up with. However it does not work.

Comment: Why do not follow the warning message, and add a line like `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)` at the top of your `CMakeLists.txt`? This warning message is longer than other parts of the build log together...

Comment: @Tsyvarev Becuase it's not relevant to the question? However I have added it, regardless.

Answer (score 1):

**CMake** variable *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* and **environment** variable *PKG_CONFIG_PATH* denote *different paths*:

- *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* points to the **installation prefix**(es) of the one or more programs.
- *PKG_CONFIG_PATH* points to **location(s) of `.pc` files**.

When CMake wants to call `pkg-config` via *pkg_check_modules* command, it translates content of *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* variable into *PKG_CONFIG_PATH* by **appending sufficies** to every path in *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* variable (see branch `if(NOT "${_extra_paths}" STREQUAL "")` in [FindPkgConfig.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake#L295)):

- `lib/pkgconfig`
- `share/pkgconfig`
- `lib32/pkgconfig` or `lib32/pkgconfig` for some distros
- some other system-specific sufficies

As you can see, you may obtain `/usr/share/pkgconfig` in *PKG_CONFIG_PATH* by using `/usr` in *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH*.

But obtaining `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig` in *PKG_CONFIG_PATH* is very questionable.

In any case, parameters described the host system itself are normally passed via environment or `cmake` arguments, not by the project's `CMakeLists.txt`. In given case command line

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig"
```

is much more simpler (and reliable) than setting *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* CMake variable.